# Swift regex for matching a decimal part of the number in a string and modify it

Tags: ios, swift, regex, replace, pattern-matching

Below is my requirement

given_string = "The total amount for **345** days is **123.4567** Euros"

the decimal part(substring) in the above string has to be inserted with spaces as shown below
converted_string = "The total amount for **345** days is **123.4 5 6 7** Euros"

I came up with below code

```
func reformatDecimalInStr() -> String {
    let pattern = "(?<=[0-9]|\\.)[0-9](?=[0-9]+)"
    return self.replacingOccurrences(of: pattern, with: "$0 ", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
}
```

but the output is like `The total amount for 34 5 days is 12 3.4 5 6 7 Euros`.
where, "345" is converted to "34 5" "123.4567" to "12 3.4 5 6 7" which is not desired

here the positive lookbehind will check for "." or a numeric
whereas what i require is "." is matched with 0 or more numeric in between.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(\G(?!^)|(?<!\d\.)\b[0-9]+\.[0-9])([0-9])
```

Replace with `$1 $2`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XYEbdi/1).

**Details**

- `(\G(?!^)|(?<!\d\.)\b[0-9]+\.[0-9])` - Group 1: the end of the preceding successful match (`\G(?!^)`) or (`|`) 1+ digits, `.` and a digit that are not immediately preceded with a digit and a dot, and that can not have a non-word char right before them (`(?<!\d\.)\b[0-9]+\.[0-9]`)
- `([0-9])` - Group 2: a digit.

Swift example:

```
let given_string = "The total amount for 345 days is 123.4567 Euros"
let regex = "(\\G(?!^)|(?<![0-9]\\.)\\b[0-9]+\\.[0-9])([0-9])"
let result = given_string.replacingOccurrences(of: regex, with: "$1 $2", options: .regularExpression)
print(result)
// => The total amount for 345 days is 123.4 5 6 7 Euros
```